# Android google analytics shows visits form russia without even installing app on any device

Tags: android, google-analytics

Android google analytics shows visits form Russia without even installing app on any device

i am trying to create an android app and just added analytics to it a few days back then i didnot use the app at all , strangely it shows some visits from russia all from same region and same service provider is it spam or any thing else

service providers are

```
Service Provider                       Sessions % Sessions
1.  
cjsc er-telecom company samara            28    70.00%
2.  
cjsc er-telecom holding samara branch      7    17.50%
```

Comment: i think its more so like this http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/74692/what-are-these-unknown-visits-to-my-private-unlisted-webpage

Comment: After spending few hours in investigating this issue I ended with settings some filters according to region and ISP . http://www.analyticsedge.com/2014/12/removing-referral-spam-google-analytics/

Comment: better still dont use the analytics id which ends with 1 you can use any other id which ends with other digits like UA-xxxxxx-2 etc

Answer (score 3):

Referral spam is a common thing where people generate fake traffic to your Google Analytics property with the referrer set to their site.  For a website, you can deal with it by using the [Referral Exclusion List](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795830?hl=en) (note: this will not apply retroactively), but for an app you'll need to use a [filter](https://megalytic.com/blog/how-to-filter-out-fake-referrals-and-other-google-analytics-spam).

Answer (score 2):

To add to my previous reply;  The device that, according to my analytics, connected via that service was running iOS.
And they were all referrals from social-buttons.com. I only found out about this site moments ago via a google search, never seen it in my life.

I'm led to believe something isn't right, it's very out of the ordinary for me to get more than 6 page visits a day, all of them being non-returning visitors. They don't navigate between pages nor do they stay for any more than 10 seconds.

I dunno if this has helped, but it'll give you a little bit of insight into it.

Comment: Edit the previous reply instead of adding another one.